# Make a div appear as though the bottom left and right corners are lifting off the page a little using box shadow?

Tags: shadow, css

Does anyone know of a tutorial on how to do this, or does anyone have a little example?

example: http://hazelmade.com/projects.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'lifted corners' example on this [CSS drop-shadows without images](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/) demo page shows it's possible without using images. It relies on CSS3 support, specifically `box-shadow` and `transform` but this is to be expected from a pure CSS solution.

Full details of the technique can be [found in the main article](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/) by Nicolas Gallagher.

Comment: awesome solution, but being css3 makes it incompatible with older browsers... if target market is newer browsers id definitely go this option. +1 :)

Comment: older browsers should be left out. Target audience is under the age of 60 years old. We shouldn't cater to ie6, but make the site at least readable, and post a nice message telling them about their horribly insecure, ugly, featureless, bad browser and tell them to upgrade to google chrome :D
ie6 users can see and read the site, but they dont get anything fancy.

Answer (score 0):

The shadow on that site is a custom made image tailored to the specific width of those elements.

If you wanted to follow a similar technique that they did, you could just add a child image absolutely positioned below the div...

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gbFNk/

HTML:

```
<div id="example">
    content here...
    <img id="shadow" src="http://hazelmade.com/images/drop_shadow.png" />
</div>
```

css:

```
#example { 
   width:796px; //your tailor made shadow needs to be this long
   height:100px;
   position:relative;
   background:grey;
}

#shadow {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-15px; //this is the height of the custom image.
}
```

Alternatively, if you need a drop shadow like that with varying width you make 2 shadows (one for each corner) and do something like the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="example">
    content here...
    <div id="dropshadow">
    <img class="left_shadow" src="leftshadow.png" />
    <img class="right_shadow" src="rightshadow.png" />
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#example { 
   width:796px;
   height:100px;
   position:relative;
   background:grey;
}

#dropshadow {
    width:796px; //needs to be the same width as the parent div
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-15px; //this still needs to be the height of the custom images.
}

#dropshadow img.left_shadow {
    float:left;
}
#dropshadow img.right_shadow {
    float:right;
}
```