# Best way to do curved shadows

Tags: html, css, slice

For something like this:

[image: box]

What would be the most effective way to do this? Best to do an image, or is there a way to achieve this with CSS without a bunch of hacks/extra markup that I dont know about?

Also the shadow only **has** to work in IE9, FF, and Chrome

Comment: You mean the horizontal gradient on the button?

Comment: I think he means the shadow below the image box.

Comment: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/

Comment: I would not recommend using CSS3 (too many - lines of css code for what?)... not this days. The easiest way is to create a good old .png image

Comment: @thirtydot You should add this as an answer because that's exactly what the OP wants. That's some CSS3 master wizardry right there. Just hope it works in IE9.

Comment: @roXon Actually it isn't that many lines of code at all, see my answer. Also, it saves on the additional HTTP request an image would require. Faster page loads times are always better in my opinion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS box shadow: Make a div appear as though the bottom left and right corners are lifting off the page a little, using box shadow? how to? link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699473/css-box-shadow-make-a-div-appear-as-though-the-bottom-left-and-right-corners-ar)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would do so using pseudo-elements and the `box-shadow` property. I have done up an example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/NWnXw/

This works in IE9 and up.

```
/* Shadow */

.shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25),
                inset 0 0 50px hsla(0,0%,0%,.05);
    position: relative;
}
.shadow:after,
.shadow:before {
    bottom: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
    content: '';
    height: 50%;
    left: 7px;
    max-width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-8deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-6deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-6deg);
         -o-transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-6deg);
            transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-6deg);
}
.shadow:after {
    -webkit-transform: skew(15deg) rotate(8deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(15deg) rotate(6deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(15deg) rotate(6deg);
         -o-transform: skew(15deg) rotate(6deg);
            transform: skew(15deg) rotate(6deg);
}
```

Comment: +1 nice demo joshnh ... (in my comment above I just thought about code reversibility, It's still hard to manipulate with some css3 methods and concatenations, or I'm still not get used to). Any way, hope one day Browsers will finally agree on the **-browser-** specifics related nomenclature, adopt default, and make our lives easier.

Comment: Rad! I couldn't think how to do this with pure CSS3. Thanks!

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work for some reason. With z-index:-1; the shadows fall behind the background. If i change it to 0 i see the shadows, but they are on top of the div. I'm trying to figure it out, but can you think of any case why this would happen?

Comment: It is to do with the z-index. It must be at least -1. Try giving the background a lower z-index again. If you are still having troubles, could you post the code, or a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 6):

Multiple [`box-shadow`](http://matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html)s

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the gradient:

`background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, from(#73B2F7), to(#6396D6));`

`background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #73B2F7,  #6396D6);`

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#73B2F7', endColorstr='#6396D6');`

If you mean shadow, I wrote a python script to create a series of div ids with widths matching those required to create half-circles in the corner and centered them in a container div above and below the text. Smaple at: http://awgwa.com .  Then you would have to position it behind the button with the gradient.